# React Native Google Authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-authentication, google-account

How can i enable logging in (*react-native init*) application with google account?

Comment: This question is on the broad side and your best bet would be googling the title of this post. There are plenty of npm packages that can help with this.

Comment: Ok, but what is the best way?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle login of any type is to use Firebase.

You can find Firebase libraries for React native here:

[- Firestack](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack)

[- React Native Firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase)

Great for all sorts of social logins including email, Twitter, Google, Facebook, etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package. I'm using this in production app and it seems to work perfectly with minimum configuration.

https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin

Comment: The above mentioned repo is not maintained any more.

Comment: Seems like it has active commits?